# Error Page Content?

Tags: 2013, content, error-handling

Does anyone know where the content lives for the PageNotFound page?

I see in the "ErrorLayout" there is a `class="error-content"` section.  I would like to edit the content for this section.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a publishing site.

In the Pages library of the rootsite there is a page called "PageNotFoundError.aspx". Just like a regular page. Edit this page to change the content of the PageNotFound page.

Even more simpler: Trigger a PageNotFound error and hit "Edit Page" in the SiteActions menu.